# Sextante - SAGA- Shape to grid question?

Tags: qgis, raster, sextante

I have a vektor shape (Index 1-5). After using the saga tool (shapes to grid) I'm getting a raster (values 1-5). The problem is that the NO DATA area is defined as 129. Is it possible to set 129 as no data? I cannot find the tool.

Comment: I know that I could use the transparency settings. But I want to set all the 129 values as "0" or "no data".